# Selenium upload file to a webpage

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to upload files to a website, that has a drop box area to upload files, I tried element.click() and it shows windows pop up to choose file, and when I tried element.send_keys('path') it raise Message: element not interactable, how to approach this problem.

here is the website: http://shareclips.net

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Upload input control opens a native dialog (it is done by browser) so clicking on the control or browse button via Selenium will just pop the dialog and the test will hang.

The workaround is to set the value of the upload input via JavaScript and then submit the form.

```py
// simulate click
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click(element).perform()
// driver is instance of webdriver
driver.find_element_by_id("IdOfInputTypeFile").send_keys(os.getcwd()+"/video.mp4")
```

`os.getcwd()` returns the current working directory. `video.mp4` is located right next to the running script in the same directory.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i have tried it like this driver.find_element_by_id("uploader-block").send_keys(os.getcwd()+"videos/video.mp4") because i have the videos in a directory named 'videos' and still get the same error element interactable.

Comment: I think selenium is not finding the element try time.sleep(10)

Comment: yeah even after the time.sleep(10) still interactable.

Comment: I found it, you need to click the element via Javascript as opposed to a "natural" click that selenium uses (to try to simulate the user experience). so check out my updated answer.

Comment: hmm i dont know what am i doing wrong, i created element = driver.find_elemnt_by_id("upload-clickable") and same error

Comment: Okey there is some progress now the page load up the choose file pop up, but the line element.send_keys(os.getcwd()+"videos/video.mp4") is giving element interactable error, while the pop up still open

Comment: well i have tried this, webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element)\
                .send_keys(os.getcwd()+"/videos/{}.mp4".format(video)) its pass show no errors but no video get uploaded to site. any ideas

Comment: I have no Idea, create new question about that, and I hope you mark my answer as correct one. @Hamza

Comment: Thanks for the help.